# Automatically update title of chart with matplotlib and pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%pylab inline

def fun (x): #piecewise functions
    if x< -1:
        return 2*x + 4 
    elif -1<= x <= 1:
        return 2*x**2
    elif x>1:
        return 2 

vfun = np.vectorize(fun)
a=-4         #as provided in question paper
b=5
N=50
x = np.linspace(a, b, N)
pylab.xlim(a, b)
pylab.ylim(vfun(x).min(), vfun(x).max())
axvline(x=-1.,color='k',ls='dashed')
axvline(x=1.,color='k',ls='dashed')
y= vfun(x)

pylab.xlabel('x')    #labeling
pylab.ylabel('y')
pylab.title('My First Plot')


plt.plot(x, y, '.')  # dotted style of line
plt.show()
```

How do i update the title if changes are made to the interval. Eg if my title is `"f(x) E [-4,5], N=50"`. If the interval is changed to `[-2,3]`, how do i make the title automatically update

Comment: Do you want an interactive plot that updates the title when you move the axvlines? Your example is not interactive (and you need to fix some small mistakes). There is an example of interactive plot [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/cursor_demo.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the current values of a, b and N:

```
pylab.title('f(x) E [{0},{1}], N={2}'.format(a,b,N))
```

Answer (score -2):

What about this?

```
pylab.title("f(x) E ["+str(a)+","+str(b)+"], N="+str(N))
```

instead of

```
pylab.title('My First Plot')
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This answer is just as valid as the other. Preferring `format` is just a matter of taste. You are welcome to only upvote the other answer, but taste should not motivate a down vote.